# Using a Regular Expression to Add Parameters Within Quotation Marks in Bash

Tags: regex, bash

I have a string stored in a file in this format:

`VAR_NAME="Param1=p1 Param2=p2"`

I need to write a regular expression which will allow me to add parameters to the variable between the quotes i.e;

`VAR_NAME="Param1=p1 Param2=p2 Param3=P3"`

I have created a RegEx which seems to work for me [here](http://regexr.com/4uk90), however, I am not sure how to implement this into my bash script.

How can I edit the above string to add parameters between quotation the marks from within a Bash script?

Comment: You seem to have got it done with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="$1 Param3=p3"`. I don't really see your problem or what do you need regexps for.

Comment: Show the the part of script you have where you are implementing the regex replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `sed`:

```
text='VAR_NAME="Param1=p1 Param2=p2"'
sed 's,VAR_NAME="\([^"]*\)",GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="\1 Param3=p3",' <<< "$text"
# => GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="Param1=p1 Param2=p2 Param3=p3"

# Or, assign the result to a variable:
result="$(sed 's,VAR_NAME="\([^"]*\)",GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="\1 Param3=p3",' <<< "$text")"
echo "$result"
# => GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="Param1=p1 Param2=p2 Param3=p3"
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/mSEo6P)